# Using Regular Expressions to parse Table of Contents

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to parse a table of contents using regular expressions. Typically the extracted lines look as follows:

4.1.2 Administrative ............................................................................................................... I-i

Or spaces instead of dots. What I need to parse are the section number - in this case 4.1.2 - the section name - Administrative - and the page number - in this case I-i.

For the section number so far I have:

```
.*(?=[.]{3,}|[ ]{3,})
```

But of course this returns 4.1.2 Administrative. First, I need some sort of lookbehind assertion that looks for the following possible combinations:

1. X, X., X.X, X.X., X.X.X, etc where X represents a digit

From there I would get the section name, and then I'd need another RE to get the section numbers X, X., X.X, X.X., etc.
Finally I would need one RE to get the page number. I thought of doing something like:

```
(?<=[.]{3,}|[ ]{3,}).*
```

But of course the above RE would not work since look-behinds do not support quantifiers such as {3,}

What I want to end up with is

```
sectionNumber = "4.1.2"
sectionName = "Administrative"
pageNumber = "I-i"
```

Any help with any of these would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one possible regex that you can use with `re.findall` and a case insensitive flag:

```
r'^([\d.]{1,5})\s([a-z]+)\s\.{10,}\s([\w-]+)'
```

Demo:

```
In [39]: re.findall(r'^([\d.]{1,5})\s([a-z]+)\s\.{10,}\s([\w-]+)', s, re.I)
Out[39]: [('4.1.2', 'Administrative', 'I-i')]
```

Note-1: The middle dots are caught by `\.{10,}` which you can change the number of repetition to a more proper one if you like. Also the trailing number is matched with `[\w-]+` that means it can match any combination of word characters (digits and alphabetical) with `-`. I'd suggest you to use a set of proper alphabetical characters that you're sure are presented at that part plus `-` inside the character class.

Note-2: Regarding `([\d.]{1,5})` for matching the section number if you think its possible to have a several-digit number inside it I'd suggest to use `([\d.]+)` or `([\d.]{1,8})` with a higher range number.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Yes I suggested that based on what OP mentioned about the format of section number. I was about to add a *Note* about that pert too.

Comment: This works perfectly. I have accepted your post since it answers the original question. But may I ask, how would this regex look if the section 'number' would be "Section I." or "Section 1." instead of only just digits such as "4.1.2"? Like if the line would look like "Section I. Administrative..........................I-i"

Comment: @PatrickMuñozVargas I think you just need to add `Section` at start of the regex.